# what is meant by Extended Data Type in varchar2?

Tags: plsql

what is the difference between both and when it is used?

```
VARCHAR2(32767) and VARCHAR2(4000)
```

12c or 11g features?
Any other datatype will accept max variable....

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to know. The obvious difference is that a column deifned as `VARCHAR2(32767)` can contain more characters then a column defined as `VARCHAR2(4000)`. But if you want to get a better answer you should post your complete stored procedure

Comment: A plsql variable of type VARCHAR2 can hold 32,767 bytes. A table column defined as VARCHAR2 can hold maximum of 4,000 bytes.

Comment: Extended data type refers to the Max_String_Size system parameter, introduced iv version 12c.  It can be set either to Standard or  Extended. If set to Standard the size limits for varchar class variables definitions remains 4000 bytes for SQL (table definition etc.) and at 32767 bytes for PLSQL. If Max_String_Size is set to Extended then the size limit is 37767 bytes for both SQL and PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with 11g or earlier, the max size for a column of type VARCHAR2 is 4000, but in PL/SQL procedures or functions, the max size for a variable or parameter of type VARCHAR2 is 32767.

This page could be useful
https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-strings

See the official documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)

> Variable-length character string having maximum length size bytes or
>   characters. Maximum size is 4000 bytes or characters, and minimum is 1
>   byte or 1 character. You must specify size for VARCHAR2. BYTE
>   indicates that the column will have byte length semantics; CHAR
>   indicates that the column will have character semantics.

But in Oracle Databast 12c maybe 32767 (http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020)

> Variable-length character string having maximum length size bytes or
>   characters. You must specify size for VARCHAR2. Minimum size is 1 byte
>   or 1 character. Maximum size is: 32767 bytes or characters if
>   MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED 4000 bytes or characters if MAX_STRING_SIZE
>   = STANDARD